# Why do we have 3 set-cookies with this HTTP?

Tags: http, curl, http-headers

I have tried

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://sportnet.rtl.hr/sportnetklub/kosarka-2/
```

I am trying to understand set-cookies.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Jul 2018 14:59:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dcf1d1aaf0cecdf86c66d953a2ad6c4dd1530716385; expires=Thu, 04-Jul-19 14:59:45 GMT; path=/; domain=.rtl.hr; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: private
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=nphhhutdgvl1yvjvzt3dhupw; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: sportnet_klub=; expires=Sun, 24-Jun-2018 15:00:07 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 435275230b1f7c60-BEG
```

Why do we get multiple values?
Does the clients OS impacts  HTTP REQUEST-RESPONSE?

Comment: Because the server application decided to set three cookies, there’s not really any other answer to give

Comment: One is for Windows clients?

Comment: They’re all for any client that makes a request

Comment: You want to say that the server does not know which OS I am using?

Comment: Not unless you tell it

Comment: @MikiBelavista It's unclear to me why you keep mentioning OS's. What makes you think that the OS has anything to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we get multiple values?

Without knowledge of the server (and proxies) you are targeting, it's hard to answer *why*. On my understanding, that's what those cookies mean:

- `__cfduid` is a Cloulflare cookie used to identify individual clients behind a shared IP address and apply security settings on a per-client basis.
- `ASP.NET_SessionId` is a cookie used in .NET applications to identify the users session on the server.
- `sportnet_klub` seems to be an application specific cookie.

---

As per the [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265), it is perfectly valid to have more than one [`Set-Cookie`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1) header in the response:

> An origin server can include multiple `Set-Cookie` header fields in a single response. [...]
>
> Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple `Set-Cookie` header fields into a single header field.  The usual mechanism for folding HTTP headers fields might change the semantics of the `Set-Cookie` header field because the `%x2C` (`,`) character is used by `Set-Cookie` in a way that conflicts with such folding.

Comment: Will server save user sessions or users to database?

Comment: @MikiBelavista _"Will server save user sessions or users to database?"_ If we don't know how the server is implemented, it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: It was mistake,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The server you are requesting towards will ask you to set certain cookies depending on their set up. These can be for session authentication, vital for the servers login system to function, or any other use you could think of. So the "why" is hard to say, it really depends on the server you are communicating with and what they use cookies for.